# database selection(db_Select)

Tags: 7, database

The database contains a *mcms_field_data_field_cage_id_vbc* table, which has more than 6000 records. I am using the following code to get the content of that table.

```
function hello_db() {
  $query = db_select('mcms_field_data_field_cage_id_vbc', 'tb');     
  $query->fields('tb', array('field_cage_id_vbc_target_id'));
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
  foreach($result as $record) {
    drupal_set_message($record);
  }
}
```

The code doesn't show all the records in that table, but a single value.

> [image: screenshot]

Why doesn't the code work as expected?

Answer (score 2):

`fetchAssoc` fetches a single record as an associative array; you're then looping over that one array and setting a message for the single column in that array, `field_cage_id_vbc_target_id`. Hence just the one result, an integer instead of the expected array(s).

You can use [`fetchAllAssoc`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchAllAssoc/7.x) instead:

```
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc();

foreach($result as $record){
  drupal_set_message($record);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

**fetchAll()** will fetch all the records.

Instated of

```
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

**fetchAssoc()** Will fetch single record.

Or

```
$result = $query->execute();
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc())
  drupal_set_message($record);
}
```

**while($record = $result->fetchAssoc())** Will fetch record one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the column of your selection with `$record -> columnname`

```
foreach($result as $record){

     drupal_set_message($record->field_cage_id_vbc_target_id);
}
```

Comment: And "**I**" don't understand **why** this works. Please add some explanation to the code you posted. Because only posting code is perceived as "low quality" (due to which your answer might be deleted via moderation).

Comment: It won't work unless the fetch method changes to one that uses objects

Comment: Are you sure? I do it this way. $result = db_select(...) and then my foreach loop. I don't use a fetch method.